# Using a MySQL trigger to update all fields matching a condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

What I am trying to do is to set the column of each insert query to the latest value of `$i` I've never used a trigger in MySQL before but I do believe that's the easiest way to do this. I would be open to other ideas and suggestions. Right now I have:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($_FILES["upload_project_images"]["name"] as $key => $name) {   
      $p_image_query = " 
        delimiter |
            CREATE TRIGGER update_start_num BEFORE INSERT ON project_images
            FOR EACH ROW 
            BEGIN
                UPDATE `project_images` SET `NEW.i_start_num` = '$i' WHERE `i_project_id` = '$prject_id' AND 'i_type' = '2';
            END |
        delimiter;
        INSERT INTO `project_images` (i_name, i_type, i_project_id,i_start_num) VALUES ('$upload_project_images_name', '2', '$project_id','$i');";

   $result=mysql_query($p_image_query) or die(mysql_error()); 
   $i++;
  }
```

The idea is that `i_start_num` is going to  equal the last `$i` so I can pick up there when updating the query.

My first idea was just to run one query after the otherbut that didn't work either I tried:

```
  $i = 1;
  foreach($_FILES["upload_project_images"]["name"] as $key => $name) {   
        //insert the file data into the database
        $p_image_query = "INSERT INTO `project_images` (i_name, i_type, i_project_id,i_start_num) VALUES ('$upload_project_images_name', '2', '$project_id','$i')"
         $result=mysql_query($p_image_query) or die(mysql_error()); 
    $i++; 

  //update the starting image id number on all project images
        $p_update_startnum_qry ="UPDATE `project_images` SET `i_start_num` = '$i' WHERE `i_project_id` = '$prject_id' AND 'i_type' = '2'";
        $p_update_startnum_qry_result=mysql_query($p_update_startnum_qry) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Which also failed.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your second example.
Could you explain a little more on what your trying to do? In the second example why do you UPDATE after the INSERT? Also if you increment $i before the UPDATE the record you just inserted will have one less.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm maybe try this:

```
// pseudo code
INSERT INTO `project_images` (i_name, i_type, i_project_id,i_start_num) 
VALUES ('$upload_project_images_name', '2', '$project_id','$i')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `project_images` 
SET `i_start_num` = '$i' 
WHERE `i_project_id` = '$prject_id' AND 'i_type' = '2'
```

Comment: Thank Phill,I actually got this to work by running the UPDATE query outside of the loop. Now the code loops through adds the images then after all images have been inserted will get the last value of $i and update all the records with that value. It works out great because I will auto increment so the last one will always be $i=1 which will be the next image number.

Comment: You should Answer your own question and select it as the solution to close the issue/question :)
Cheers!